# Go not allowed to build absolute path

Tags: go

I'm trying to automate go build via exec.Command, my command is like :

```sh
exec.Command("/usr/bin/go", "build", "/path/to/my/go/project")
```

but the compiler said

> cannot import absolute path

note: `/path/to/my/go/project` is folder that contain `go.mod`

Comment: packages are referenced by import path, and the go tools work with packages

Comment: As the error says, the go command does not take absolute paths. Set the working directory to the package you want to build.

Comment: yeah, fixed ```    cmd := exec.Command(gobin, "build", "-o", "binbin")
    cmd.Dir = path
    cmd.Run()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The packages are relative to the import path. There is no capability to import 'absolutely'.

While it is not spelt out specifically in the spec, it does allude to it at https://golang.org/ref/spec#ImportPath:

> The interpretation of the ImportPath is implementation-dependent but it is typically a substring of the full file name of the compiled package and may be relative to a repository of installed packages.

There are variations on relative importing and vendoring that might work for you (see GO 1.5 vendoring experiment, now available in 1.6 https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Bz5-UB7g2uPBdOx-rw5t9MxJwkfpx90cqG9AFL0JAYo/edit?pref=2&pli=1)

another way: you can add Working_dir in your cmd.Dir variable.

```
cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/go", "build")
cmd.Dir = "/path/to/my/go/project"
cmd.Run()
```